# Hidden files in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, total-commander

I have a hidden file, but I couldn't see it in "Explore" (My computer). Then, I downloaded Total Commander, and I was able to see the hidden file.

In Tools->Folder Options, I have: `Show hidden files & folders` - checked, and `Hide protected os files` - unchecked.

Why can't I see this hidden file in "Explorer"?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the folder you downloaded the file to? I know it might sound like a stupid question to ask, but from time to time we all overlook the obvious.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: What is the name of the hidden file?

Comment: I was don't remember. I was delete him

Comment: Some files remain hidden in windows, not sure why.

This file for instance is always hidden on any of my Windows systems, I can however type the path in the explorer bar and it will show the contents.

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution is that your PC is infected, and a Root-Kit is hiding the file from the explorer.

Comment: If it was a rootkit the other file manager would not see it either, it would be hidden at the kernel level, hence the name "rootkit" But it could be some other kind of infection.

Answer (score 1):

If I undestand your question correctlly, your problem is simple.

Total Commander, shows hidden files by default, But Windows Explorer doesn't.

So what you need to do is:

**WINDOWS XP:**

1. On the Tools menu in Windows Explorer, click Folder Options.
2. Click the View tab.
3. Under Hidden files and folders, click Show hidden files and folders.

**VISTA:**

1. Click the round blue Start thing in the left corner
2. Click Control Panel
3. Click Folder Options
4. Click the View tab
5. Click Show hidden files and folders
6. If you want to see system files as well, unclick Hide protected operating system files   (Recommended)
7. Click OK

**[WINDOWS 7](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial151.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You just copy & paste the next paragraph texts in a text file and save it as xyz.vbs and run it.

```
on Error Resume Next
Dim objShell, objFileSystem, objTextStream, objRegex
Dim colRegexMatches1, colRegexMatches2
Dim nReturnCode
Dim strIpFileText
Dim element, i
Dim Lista
Lista=array("qd*.cmd")
Set geekside=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives
Wscript.Echo "Software provided by *PremanandPrasad*"
nret33=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\ /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f",0,TRUE)
nret43=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\ /v SuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f",0,TRUE)
nret44=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\ /v ShowSuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f",0,TRUE)
nret45=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\ /v Hidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f",0,TRUE)
nret46=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\ /v SuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f",0,TRUE)
nret47=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\ /v ShowSuperHidden /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f",0,TRUE)
nret34=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\NOHIDDEN\ /v CheckedValue /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f",0,TRUE)
nret35=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\NOHIDDEN\ /v DefaultValue /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f",0,TRUE)
nret36=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL\ /v CheckedValue /f",0,TRUE)
nret37=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL\ /v CheckedValue /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f",0,TRUE)
nret38=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\SHOWALL\ /v DefaultValue /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f",0,TRUE)
nret39=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\SuperHidden\ /v CheckedValue /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f",0,TRUE)
nret40=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\SuperHidden\ /v DefaultValue /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f",0,TRUE)
nret48=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Folder\Hidden\ /v Type /t REG_SZ /d Group /f",0,TRUE)
nret61=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\ /v NoFolderOptions /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f",0,TRUE)
nret62=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\ /v NoFolderOptions /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f",0,TRUE)
nret63=geekside.Run("cmd /C reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v DisableRegistryTools /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f",0,TRUE)
nret78=geekside.Run("cmd /C taskkill /f /im explorer.exe",0,TRUE)
nret79=geekside.Run("cmd /C start explorer.exe",0,TRUE)
WScript.Echo "Congratulations! You can see your Hidden Files & Folder now"
WScript. Quit(0)
```